# Issues with Line Breaks when trying to Sever and execute a PHP generated bash script

Tags: php, bash

Trying to Execute a bash script I'm serving on the fly using:

```
wget -O- "https://endpoint.com/my/script/" | bash
```

When download the script and run the following to clean up the line breaks first it works fine:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ~/myscript.sh
```

If I try to run it directly from wget the linebreak format is an issue.  I've tried this and a few reg_ex functions off of here, but I can't seem to find anything that works to do it in php itself before serving the file

```
echo str_replace("\r\n", "\r", $bash);
```

I would really like to avoid actually saving the physical file if it's possible to avoid it, but haven't managed yet.

Comment: why not an extra pipe? i.e. `curl .... | sed 's/\r$//' | bash` ? Or am I misunderstanding your Q? Good luck.

Comment: That would work, but I'm trying to get it parsing properly on the server side in the first place.

Comment: I'm guessing there is php code that we need to see to understand your problem. Please read [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter the problem is as described it's got nothing to do with my code specifically beyond php's native functionality.  PHP generates windows styled line breaks, which wont parse in a unix shell script.  That's all that sed function does, is switch from windows to unix style line breaks after which the code runs correctly.  I just can't find a way to do the same in php.  I know the problem.  I know how to fix the problem in bash, I just can't find a solution in php.